# serial read changes input & doesn't read whole line

Tags: c++, stream, serial-port, arduino-uno

Large strings sent over serial are not correctly read using an Arduino Uno and the Arduino IDE. When the typed command is too long, not the whole data is returned and sometimes is is even random numbers.

`99,3,0,1,0,0,0` Results correctly in (not sure why there is an ending `,` tho): 
`receivedValues are: 99,3,0,1,0,0,0,`

`99,3,0,0,0,0,0` Results correctly in: `receivedValues are: 99,3,0,0,0,0,0,`

Where is starts to go wrong:

`99,3,0,100,200,300,400` Results in: `receivedValues are: 99,3,0,100,200,44,144,`

`99,123456789` Results in: `receivedValues are: 99,21,0,1,200,200,244,`

`99,3,0,1,200,200,2000` Results in: `receivedValues are: 99,3,0,1,200,200,208,`

Here is the part of my code that is relevant:

```
uint8_t receivedValues[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

#define HEADER 0 // 99
#define CMD   1 // LICHT (2)   || GEUR (3)
#define DATA0 2 // KLEUR INDEX || GEUR INDEX
#define DATA1 3 // H           || ON / OFF
#define DATA2 4 // S
#define DATA3 5 // V
#define DATA4 6 // BlendTime

#define CHECK 99

#define ON 1
#define OFF 0

bool messageReceived = false;
bool startBlending = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  ParseSerial();
  if (messageReceived)
  {
    printMessage();
    // CheckCommand();
    messageReceived = false;
  }
}


void ParseSerial()
{
  int serialIndex = 0;
  if (Serial.available() > 8)
  {
    while (0 < Serial.available())
    {
      String bufferString;
      int bufferInt;

      bufferString = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
      bufferInt = bufferString.toInt();
      receivedValues[serialIndex] = bufferInt;

      serialIndex++;
    }
    if (receivedValues[HEADER] == CHECK)
    {
      Serial.print("receivedValues[0]: ");
      Serial.println(receivedValues[0]);
      messageReceived = true;
    }
    if (receivedValues[HEADER] != CHECK)
    {
      Serial.println("not a good package");
    }
    Serial.flush();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.flush();
  }
}

void printMessage()
{
  Serial.print("receivedValues are: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(receivedValues[i]);
    Serial.print(",");
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

If the header of the message does not start with `99` it will write `not a good package`. What is noticeable it that when I do enter a command with `99` at the beginning ONCE, it will write `not a good package` twice most of the time.

Comment: Exactly what is the message format?  Is the data being transmitted as ASCII text or binary values?  Do the sender and receiver have the same architecture?

Comment: @jwdonahue Right now I am using the Arduino IDE serial monitor to input messages. (Arduino Uno).

Comment: So that would likely be a terminal emulator, implying transmission as ASCII text?  Please post an [mcve].  I have no clue what a `String` is in this context and no clue how `Serial` is defined, and there is no async serial code to evaluate how you are reading/writing the serial port (or are you polling?).

Comment: Does `Serial.readStringUntil(',')` leave the comma in the buffer, read it and throw it away, or append it to `bufferString`?  This code does not look like C code.  It's kind of more C++'ish.

Comment: @jwdonahue the Arduino language is c/c++. The posted code will reproduce the problem, I stripped out all unnecessary code.

Comment: So this is C++ code, not C.  You are using classes, it can't be C.

Comment: I don't get why you are being so difficult. `the Arduino language is merely a set of C/C++ functions that can be called from your code` literally copied from https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/FAQ. And why are you saying I refuse to post an minimal reproducible example?? Copy the code I posted in the Arduio IDE, it complies and reproduces the problem that I am asking a question about. In the meantime I found an answer, and I hope that this post will help somebody in the future. Thank you for your time @jwdonahue :)

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language.  You put  a C tag on the post, it's not C code.  Technically, it's not a valid C++ program either, it doesn't have a `main` function.  There are no include statements for header files to declare the class interfaces you are using.  I wasn't on this thread because of the Arduino tag, I was on it because of the C tag and I was just trying help you improve the quality of your question, so that it might actually be a useful thread in the future.

Comment: regarding: `99,3,0,1,200,200,2000`  the 2000 will not fit into a `uint8_t` so the data gets corrupted

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for your feedback, I have changed the tags and clarified my question for future use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Changing uint8_t was not the answer.

> A byte of 8 binary bits can represent 28 = 256 numbers: 0 - 255. The
>   serial connection sends data byte by byte, so if you want to send a
>   number larger than 255, you'll have to send multiple bytes

Link to source:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=492055.0

I ended up sending a smaller number (minutes) than 255, and then in the Arduino code multiply it again (to seconds).

Comment: Congrats on figuring that one out yourself! Didn't think of that. Feel free to accept your own answer, so that future visitors know this solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will, apparently you can accept your own question two days later.

Answer (score 1):

`receivedValues` is declared as `uint8_t receivedValues[7]`. The maximum value for `uint8_t` is 255. If you try to store a larger number, it will be truncated.

If you want to store larger numbers, you need to pick a wider integer type for your array, e.g.

```
uint32_t receivedValues[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Which will work up to `UINT32_MAX`, which is `0xFFFFFFFF` (`4294967295`)

Comment: That looks like a logic fix, but the problem persists (even with uint32_t): input `99,3,1,100,100,100,1000` outputs like: `receivedValues are: 99,3,1,100,10000,0,0,`